# ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'receive'

Tags: solidity, remix

How can I call payable function from the A contract in B contract and send msg.value to it when invoking fund function from B contract

```
interface A {
    receive() external payable;
}

contract B {
    A a;
    constructor() {
        a = A("0xE9F920eE6F15739cc3b2Ac5Ea862C6eB9EEE529b");
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        a.receive();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'receive'
--> fallback/fallback.sol:12:11:
|
12 | a.receive();
| ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The `receive()` function is similar to the fallback function but makes it explicit that it can only **receive** ETH, without any implementation.

You cannot call it like that, but instead the `receive()` function will be called when the calldata is empty.

Change to that:

```
contract B {
    address payable a;

    constructor() {
        a = payable(0xE9F920eE6F15739cc3b2Ac5Ea862C6eB9EEE529b);
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        a.call{value: msg.value}("");
    }
}
```